# Python copy a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I'm using python 3.4.1.
For a single list `a=[1,2]`, if I make a copy of it, `b = a.copy()` when I change items in `b`, it won't change items in `a`.
However, when I define a list of lists (actually a matrix) `a = [[1,2],[3,4]]`, when I assign `b = a.copy()`. What I do to list `b` actually affects `a`.
I checked their addresses, they are different.
Can anyone tell me why?

ps: What I did is `b[0][0] = x`, and the item in a was also changed.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From the docs for the [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) module:

> The difference between shallow and deep copying is only relevant for compound objects (objects that contain other objects, like lists or class instances):
>
> - A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.
> - A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

When you call regular `copy.copy()` you are performing a *shallow* copy. This means that in a case of a list-of-lists, you will get a new copy of the outer list, but it will contain the original inner lists as its elements. Instead you should use `copy.deepcopy()`, which will create a new copy of both the outer and inner lists.

The reason that you didn't notice this with your first example of using `copy([1,2])` is that the primitives like `int` are immutable, and thus it is impossible to change their value without creating a new instance. If the contents of the list had instead been mutable objects (like lists, or any user-defined object with mutable members), any mutation of those objects would have been seen in both copies of the list.

Comment: Thank you! And one more question about copy. Can I get a copy of a class? Like the tree class, can I get a copy of some tree object t1 using a simple way?

Comment: Yes, you can use the `copy` module on any object that defines the `__copy__` and `__deepcopy__` methods. See the linked documentation in the original answer for specifics. There is not, sadly, a 'pre-defined' copy operation in Python like there is in languages like C++ (which is usually a good thing, because C++'s auto-generated copy-constructor is often wrong for any non-trivial class).

Comment: @jack You can check what is going on when you use the copy method  on [pythontutor.com](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a+%3D+%5B%5B1,+2%5D,+%5B3,+4%5D%5D%0Ab+%3D+a.copy()%0Ab%5B0%5D%5B0%5D+%3D+9&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=0). You can see all of the pointers visualized there.

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps a list comprehension as such:

```
new_list = [x[:] for x in old_list]
```

...though if your matrices are deeper than one layer, list comprehension is probably less elegant than just using `deepcopy`.

edit - a shallow copy, as stated, will still contain references to the objects inside the list. So for example...

```
>>> this = [1, 2]
>>> that = [33, 44]
>>> stuff = [this, that]
>>> other = stuff[:]
>>> other
[[1, 2], [33, 44]]
>>> other[0][0] = False
>>> stuff
[[False, 2], [33, 44]]    #the same problem as before
>>> this
[False, 2]                #original list also changed
>>> other = [x[:] for x in stuff]
>>> other
[[False, 2], [33, 44]]
>>> other[0][0] = True
>>> other
[[True, 2], [33, 44]]
>>> stuff
[[False, 2], [33, 44]]    #copied matrix is different
>>> this
[False, 2]                #original was unchanged by this assignment
```

Comment: It's also a lot less clear to a casual reader what it's doing than using methods from `copy`, though it is slightly more performant.

Comment: Sure, there's that. But list comprehensions are most pythonic, so I guess it depends on what is considered 'clear', and to whom. In any event, if the matrix is too nested then my suggestion wouldn't be very helpful, but for a single dimension I don't think it is too bad

Answer (score -21):

It's very simply, just do that:

```
b = a
```

Exemple:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> b.append(4)
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: This just makes `a` and `b` point to the same object. It is not a correct solution