# Multidimensionnal array class and line object in Python

Tags: python, object, multidimensional-array

I have a question that spawned from writing my own class to manage a two-dimension table.

I started by creating a simple class as follows, creating an empty_line object that was copied as much as needed to create the number of lines:

```
class Table(object):
"""Table class, allows the creation of new lines and columns to the table"""
def __init__(self, col = 1, lines = 1, defaultcontent=''):
    self.columns = col
    self.lines = lines
    self.empty_line = [defaultcontent for i in range(self.columns)]
    self.table = [self.empty_line for j in range(self.lines)]

def add_line(self):
    self.table.append(self.empty_line)
    self.lines += 1

def add_column(self):
    self.empty_line.append('')
    for i in range(self.lines):
        self.table[i].append('')
```

However, after I created a table, for example with `table = Table(5,3)`, and do an assignment with `table.table[1][2] = 'something'`, I realised the `'something'` found itself in every line, and that I couldn't change a single line without having the others changed. Also, `self.empty_line` was changed.

After a little while, I wrapped my head around the problem being in the `self.empty_line` usage. I rewrote my class, this time taking out the `self.empty_line` and replacing it with the primitive `['' for i in range(self.columns)]` (and of course also correcting the bug in the `add_column()` method that would add two columns instead of just one!).

My problem went away, but a question still lingers: Shouldn't the         `self.table = [self.empty_line for j in range(self.lines)]` create a copy of the `self.empty_line` object for every new line, instead of somehow 'linking' the same `self.empty_line` instance (that gets changed).

So what am I doing wrong, and where is the hole in my knowledge about python objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
self.empty_line = [defaultcontent for i in range(self.columns)]
self.table = [self.empty_line for j in range(self.lines)]
```

The empty_line is copied in every line of the table using swallow copy. You copied only references, not the default content.

To fix that:

```
self.table = [[default_content] * self.columns for _ in range(self.lines)]
```

Same problem with add_line.
Don't store empty_line but use default_content instead.

```
self.table.append([self.default_content] * self.columns)
...
```

See: [Python copy a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684154/python-copy-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: This is what I needed to get around this concept, the shallow/deep copy difference! Thanks a lot!