# why does a list change after looping

Tags: python, python-3.x

there is a list, after looping, it changes. But I do nothing to change it, just use it.

```
a = [[1,1,1,1], [0,0,1,1], [1,1,0,0], [0,0,0,0]]
b = a[:]
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
       b[i][j] = a[j][i]
```

then a becomes [[1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]

I really appreciate it if someone tells me what happened and how to fix this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python copy a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684154/python-copy-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying nested lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541865/copying-nested-lists-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b` is not a deep copy of `a` it just holds references to the same arrays `a` does. When you alter the children in `b` you are altering the same elements in `a`.

You don't need to copy the array first. Since you are adding elements to b in order, you can just append as you go:

```
a = [[1,1,1,1], [0,0,1,1], [1,1,0,0], [0,0,0,0]]
b = []
for i in range(4):
    b.append([])
    for j in range(4):
        b[i].append(a[j][i])
```

You can also get the same result much simpler with:

```
a = [[1,1,1,1], [0,0,1,1], [1,1,0,0], [0,0,0,0]]
list(zip(*a))
```

Answer (score 0):

> I really appreciate it if someone tells me what happened and how to fix this problem.

About fixing this problem: if you want `b` to be a copy of `a`, you can use the [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) module:

```
import copy
a = [[1,1,1,1], [0,0,1,1], [1,1,0,0], [0,0,0,0]]
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
```