# Python list copy - Confused

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python beginner here. Reading article about list references, shallow and deep copies, tried out the following:

```py
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = list(a)
a[0] = 'A'
```

Expected output:

```py
>>>a
['A', 'b', 'c']
>>>b
['A', 'b', 'c']
```

Actual output:

```py
>>>a
['A', 'b', 'c']
>>>b
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

However, it is working in the following case:

```py
xs = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> ys = list(xs)  # Make a shallow copy

xs[1][0] = 'X'

>>> xs
[[1, 2, 3], ['X', 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> ys
[[1, 2, 3], ['X', 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Can someone explain if I am missing something here? 
Thank you

Python 3.7.4

article link: https://realpython.com/copying-python-objects/

Comment: What article? You can't distinguish between a deep and shallow copy on a list of immutable objects.

Comment: list() function takes any iterable as an argument, so it creates a new list object.
Try list(open('text_file', 'r').read())

Comment: I understand that it creates a new list object, but it creates a shallow copy, meaning it is one level deep only. List object is new, but elements of list are still references to the child elements of the original list. I will update my question with the code where it is actually working

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/28684234/9510611 the answer here answers your question

Comment: @KevinGlasson perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `list()` fuction makes a NEW list, if you do an change to your original list after the assignation, the new list won't change.

You can do that using a variable value, but be careful, for example

```py
var = 'a'
list1 = [var, 'a', 'b']
list2 = list1

print(list1)
print(list2)
```

**output:**

```
['a', 'a', 'b']
['a', 'a', 'b']
```

You can change the value of `var` and both lists will change, except if you this:

```py
var = 'a'
list1 = [var, 'a', 'b']
var = 'c'
list2 = list1

print(list1)
print(list2)
```

**output:**

```
['a', 'a', 'b']
['a', 'a', 'b']
```

**Why?**
Because when you do `list1=[var, 'a', 'b']` `var` has the value of `'a'`, but when you change its value, this won't affect the `list1` because it SAVED the value of `var` itself, so `list2` neither

Comment: Damn I saw your update... it blown my mind up lmao

Answer (score 0):

`list()` creates a new list, meaning changes to the original won't affect the new one.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `b = list(a)`, you are making a new list `b` whose values are the same as those in `a`. At that point, the elements of each list are equal, but they are not the same object. That is, a change in one of those objects is not reflected in the other. They are independent.

If you say `b = a`, you are saying that `b` and `a` are names that reference the same object.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for yourself what's going on by looking at the 'id' on the object. You can see that `b = a` creates a new entry in the namespace that simply references the same object as `a`, but `c = a[:]` and `d = list(a)` both create new objects that copy in the contents of a.

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
id(a)
Out[60]: 4690845768

b = a
id(b)
Out[62]: 4690845768

c = a[:]
id(c)
Out[65]: 4690851848

d = list(a)
id(d)
Out[67]: 4690846728
```

You've just added the following scenario to the question:

```
xs = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
ys = list(xs)
```

It's true that xs and ys are different objects:

```
id(ys)
Out[70]: 4691198664
id(xs)
Out[71]: 4690895496
```

But the nested lists are themselves objects. `ys = list(xs)` created a new object, but copied the contents - the three nested list objects, across.

```
id(ys[0])
Out[72]: 4690898696
id(xs[0])
Out[73]: 4690898696
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are expecting is `b = a` - this will make 'b' reference the SAME list (object) as 'a'.

When you do `b = list(a)` You create a **new** list that is independent of 'a'.

Comment: Thanks!  When it is just a reference, it is clear that it will give the result, however I was experimenting with shallow copies and trying to understand the behaviour