# Python alters original list despite using list.copy()

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, copy, shallow-copy

So I just encountered something weird.

I had problems with copying lists and altering when I started programming, then learned that I had to use `my_list.copy()` to get an actual copy. Now I just stumbled upon the same effect, despite using `list.copy()`.

So here is an example:

```
ori = [['1', '2', '3'],['1', '2', '3'],['1', '2', '3'],['1', '2', '3']]
copy = ori.copy()

for i, item in enumerate(copy):
    del copy[i][0]

print('Original list: ', ori)
print('Copy of list: ', copy)
```

What I expected as output:

```
Original list: [['1', '2', '3'],['1', '2', '3'],['1', '2', '3'],['1', '2', '3']]
Copy of list: [['2', '3'], ['2', '3'], ['2', '3'], ['2', '3']]
```

Actual output:

```
Original list: [['2', '3'],['2', '3'],['2', '3'],['2', '3']]
Copy of list: [['2', '3'], ['2', '3'], ['2', '3'], ['2', '3']]
```

So I guess my question is: Is this expected behaviour? Do I need to use `copy.deepcopy()` or is there another solution with built in tools?

I am using Python 3.8.1 on the PC I just had this 'issue'.

Comment: This is because you've just done a "shallow" copy. For more info please [read the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html). Specifically about `copy.deepcopy`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684154/python-copy-a-list-of-lists

Comment: Thanks guys, I just read the documentation 2 minutes before posting the question. Guess I must have skipped over the part about collection of objects. @HampusLarsson I don't think your link applies 100%, as I used the built in function. Same logic applies though.

Comment: @n00by0815 It does apply 100%. When you call `list.copy()` it calls `copy` on itself, which itself is the same as `copy.copy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `copy()` method returns a shallow copy of the list.
Use `copy.deepcopy()` instead.