# Original list still modifies even though copy is made

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list `currentCell` which contains info like coordinates and values and stuff. I then create a copy of that list using `currentCellNew = currentCell.copy()`. Im told that doing that and modifying the copy will NOT effect the original. But when i remove something from the copy, it also removes it from the original list.

Here is the code that removes from the copy:

```
#some variables exist outside of scope
        currentCell       = next(x for x in self.cells if x[0] == currentCellCoords)
        currentCellNew    = currentCell.copy()
        if currentCellNew[3] == 0:
            if **condition**:
                wallAxis = next(x[0] for x in list(self.Orientations.items()) if x[1] == "f")

#### Here is the code that removes the element from the copy #####
                currentCellNew[2].remove(next(x for x in currentCellNew[2] if x[0] == wallAxis))
```

Comment: Please post a [mre]. The current code won't run and reproduce your error if one were to run it as-is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python copy a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684154/python-copy-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: Yes it does, ShadowRanger pointed out the same solution. Thank you

Comment: The comment is automatically posted when we vote to close the question as a duplicate. ShadowRanger should have done this instead of adding an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.copy()` is a shallow copy; it's fine when the original `list` contains immutable objects, but it looks like you've got a `list` of `list`s, and those inner `list`s aren't being copied (the new outer `list` has references to the same inner `list`s as the first one).

You need to use [the `copy.deepcopy` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) to perform the original copy, thereby copying the contents, not just the top-level references:

```
import copy   # At top of file

...
currentCellNew    = copy.deepcopy(currentCell)
```

Comment: Ah i see, so list.copy() will not copy any nested lists. Thank you