# Why is function changing list values in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, copy

i tried calling .copy on it and then passing it in the function. that didn't work.
when i tried coppying in the function itself it still changed the original list.
the function is in another file

main.py

`win_condition.check_r_win(board)`

win_condition.py

```
def check_r_win(board):
    board = _board.copy()
    for col in board:
        while(len(col) <= ROWS):
            col.append("-")
```

Comment: Presumably board is a list *of mutable objects* (more lists?) and you're only doing a *shallow* copy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python copy a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684154/python-copy-a-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you are trying here. Python's *list* is a **mutable** object type. If you pass a object reference of a list to a function and change the list within this function, it also gets changed outside of the function scope.