# Python lists always assign reference not value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, reference

I want to copy list values to another list because I modify the original one and use the new one. Bu t whatever I try it will alwasy assign reference not value.

```
class Chromosome:

    def __init__(self):
        self.matrix = [[0 for x in range(LENGTH)] for y in range(LENGTH)]

class Population:

    def __init__(self, start):
        self.start = start
        self.chromosomes = []

    def crossover(self):
        for index in range(0, POPULATION_SIZE - 1, 2):
           swap_point = random.randint(7, 10)
           matrix1 = self.chromosomes[index].matrix
           matrix2 = self.chromosomes[index + 1].matrix
           self.chromosomes[index].crossover(matrix2, swap_point)
           self.chromosomes[index + 1].crossover(matrix1, swap_point)
```

The following lines is that ı wan to assign values not reference

`matrix1 = self.chromosomes[index].matrix[:]` and
`matrix2 = self.chromosomes[index + 1].matrix[:]`

I tried followings

`list(self.chromosomes[index + 1].matrix)`

`self.chromosomes[index + 1].matrix[:]`

`self.chromosomes[index + 1].matrix.copy()`

How can I get values of the chromosome to matrix1 and matrix2?

Comment: Try copy.deepcopy

Comment: For further elaboration see [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28684234/21146235)

Comment: Be sure to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `deepcopy()` from `copy` library:

```
from copy import deepcopy

A = [[1,2], [3,4]]
B = deepcopy(A)
A[0][0] = 5

print(B)

# output: [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```